# Converting Instant to LocalDate and back

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, datetime-conversion

I have a problem with converting dates between `Instant` and `LocalDate` and back. I need to change my date to monday in its current week (if it's wednesday then I'm changing to monday):

```
public static Instant getStartDateAsMonday(Instant startTime) {
    LocalDate monday = startTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    startTime = monday.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    return startTime;
}
```

When I test it ...

```
@Test
public void testGetStartDateAsMonday() {
    Instant instant = DateHelperService.getStartDateAsBeginningOnMonday(
        Instant.parse("2020-05-27T00:00:00Z"));
    assertThat(instant).isEqualTo("2020-05-25T00:00:00Z");
}
```

... the test doesn't pass and gives the output:

```
Expected : 2020-05-25T00:00:00Z
Actual   : 2020-05-24T22:00:00Z
```

My system default timezone is *GMT+2*. The test passes when I do `atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC"))`, but I don't understand why I can't use my system default in that conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, calling `ZoneId.systemDefault()` twice is bad practice. The JVM’s current default time zone may have changed between calls. Any code in any thread of any app within that JVM can change the current default time zone with immediate effect.

So, capture the current default.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

You said:

> My system default timezone is GMT+2

`GMT+2` represents an offset not a time zone. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, positive or negative. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region`.

You said:

> Expected : 2020-05-25T00:00:00Z
>
> Actual   : 2020-05-24T22:00:00Z

Your expectation is incorrect. If you have a moment representing the first moment of the day in a zone such as `Europe/Brussels` or `Africa/Cairo` for a time-of-day of 00:00, and you know that zone runs two hours ahead of UTC on that date, then intuitively you know UTC is two hours earlier. If the clock strikes midnight in Brussels or Cairo, you know the clock cannot yet be striking midnight in UTC, at the Greenwich Royal Observatory, or in Iceland. Midnight won’t strike there for two more hours. So the date is still “yesterday” in UTC. And two hours earlier than 00:00 is 22:00. So your actual result is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through it method by method:

```java
LocalDate monday = startTime // startTime is 2020-05-27 00:00:00 as an Instant.

    // 2020-05-27 02:00:00, but with GMT+2 information as it is a ZonedDateTime now.
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())

    // (1) 2020-05-27 02:00:00 without any zone information.
    // (2) 2020-05-27 00:00:00 because hour is dropped as it's a LocalDate here.
    .toLocalDate()

    // Changed to 2020-05-25 00:00:00, which is what you want.
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));

startTime = monday // monday is 2020-05-25 00:00:00 as LocalDate.

    // You say that this is at GMT+2 and you want the start of day.
    // You get a ZonedDateTime 2020-05-25 00:00:00 with information about GMT+2.
    .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())

    // Instant has no zone offset, so this is what the ZonedDateTime needs to consider.
    // 2020-05-25 00:00:00 becomes 2020-05-24 22:00:00 as the +2 offset is subtracted.
    .toInstant();
```

When you are using `ZoneId.of("UTC")` no problems will happen as the offset of `ZoneId.of("UTC")` is zero (daylight saving stuff ignored for simplicity). A datetime minus zero hours is the same datetime.